# Not able to send HTTP/2 GET request using scapy and scapy ssl library

Tags: python, websocket, scapy, tls1.2, http2

I am trying to send HTTP/2 GET request over TLS 1.2 using scapy ssl library. The code is given below. I am not getting any error but the web page is also not received. Please let me know what are the issues with the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import print_function
import socket
import sys

try:
    # This import works from the project directory
    from scapy_ssl_tls.ssl_tls import *
except ImportError:
    # If you installed this package via pip, you just need to execute this
    from scapy.layers.ssl_tls import *

tls_version = TLSVersion.TLS_1_2


def tls_hello(sock):
    client_hello = TLSRecord(version=tls_version) / TLSHandshake() /\
                   TLSClientHello(version=tls_version, compression_methods=[TLSCompressionMethod.NULL, ],
                                  cipher_suites=[TLSCipherSuite.ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, ], extensions=[TLSExtension() /
                                      TLSExtALPN(protocol_name_list=[TLSALPNProtocol(data="h2"),
                                      TLSALPNProtocol(data="h2-16"),
                                      TLSALPNProtocol(data="h2-14"),
                                      TLSALPNProtocol(data="http/1.1"),
                                                                          ])],)
                                  # cipher_suites=[TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, ])
                                  # cipher_suites=[TLSCipherSuite.RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, ])
                                  # cipher_suites=[TLSCipherSuite.DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, ])
                                  # cipher_suites=[TLSCipherSuite.DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, ])
    sock.sendall(client_hello)
    server_hello = sock.recvall()
    server_hello.show()


def tls_client_key_exchange(sock):
    client_key_exchange = TLSRecord(version=tls_version) / TLSHandshake() / sock.tls_ctx.get_client_kex_data()
    client_ccs = TLSRecord(version=tls_version) / TLSChangeCipherSpec()
    sock.sendall(TLS.from_records([client_key_exchange, client_ccs]))
    sock.sendall(to_raw(TLSFinished(), sock.tls_ctx))
    server_finished = sock.recvall()
    server_finished.show()


def tls_client(ip):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect(ip)
        sock = TLSSocket(sock, client=True)
        print("Connected to server: %s" % (ip,))
    except socket.timeout:
        print("Failed to open connection to server: %s" % (ip,), file=sys.stderr)
    else:
        tls_hello(sock)
        tls_client_key_exchange(sock)
        print("Finished handshake. Sending application data (GET request)")
    print("+++++++++++++++++")
    sock.sendall(to_raw(TLSPlaintext(data="PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n"), sock.tls_ctx))
    #sock.sendall(to_raw(TLSPlaintext(data="GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: localhost\r\n\r\n"), sock.tls_ctx))
    print("+++++++++++++++++")   
    resp = sock.recvall()
        print("Got response from server")
        resp.show()
        print(sock.tls_ctx)
    finally:
        sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        server = (sys.argv[1], int(sys.argv[2]))
    else:
        server = ("127.0.0.1", 443)
    tls_client(server)
```

The output which I am getting is:

```
Connected to server: ('127.0.0.1', 443)
###[ SSL/TLS ]###
  \records   \
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= handshake
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x55
   |###[ TLS Handshake ]###
   |     type      = server_hello
   |     length    = 0x51
   |###[ TLS Server Hello ]###
   |        version   = TLS_1_2
   |        gmt_unix_time= 1964528416
   |        random_bytes= '\xa5\x11\x11\x81\xc3V\x03Q\xdb>\x8b\x1d\x9e\x13\xa7\xfelT\x80\x97\xf5\x06.4\x18\xc8\x85X'
   |        session_id_length= 0x20
   |        session_id= '\x93\xfd\x95\xbc\x1d68w\x19{8\x83dz\xb4\\r\x81\xb7&\xb5\x14\x1d\xfc<fR\x00\xe7\xd3{\x90'
   |        cipher_suite= ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
   |        compression_method= NULL
   |        extensions_length= 0x9
   |        \extensions\
   |         |###[ TLS Extension ]###
   |         |  type      = application_layer_protocol_negotiation
   |         |  length    = 0x5
   |         |###[ TLS Extension Application-Layer Protocol Negotiation ]###
   |         |     length    = 0x3
   |         |     \protocol_name_list\
   |         |      |###[ TLS ALPN Protocol ]###
   |         |      |  length    = 0x2
   |         |      |  data      = 'h2'
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= handshake
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x41f
   |###[ TLS Handshake ]###
   |     type      = certificate
   |     length    = 0x41b
   |###[ TLS Certificate List ]###
   |        length    = 0x418
   |        \certificates\
   |         |###[ TLS Certificate ]###
   |         |  length    = 0x415
   |         |  \data      \
   |         |   |###[ Raw ]###
   |         |   |  load      = '0\x82\x04\x110\x82\x02\xf9\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\t\x00\xf6\x7f)\x04Yq\x7f\x830\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x0b\x05\x000\x81\x9e1\x0b0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02IN1\x170\x15\x06\x03U\x04\x08\x0c\x0eMadhya-Pradesh1\x0f0\r\x06\x03U\x04\x07\x0c\x06Indore1\x130\x11\x06\x03U\x04\n\x0c\nIIT Indore1\r0\x0b\x06\x03U\x04\x0b\x0c\x04DCSE1\x180\x16\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x0c\x0fhttp2.nikhil.me1\'0%\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\t\x01\x16\x18phd1401101002@iiti.ac.in0\x1e\x17\r170403070657Z\x17\r200402070657Z0\x81\x9e1\x0b0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02IN1\x170\x15\x06\x03U\x04\x08\x0c\x0eMadhya-Pradesh1\x0f0\r\x06\x03U\x04\x07\x0c\x06Indore1\x130\x11\x06\x03U\x04\n\x0c\nIIT Indore1\r0\x0b\x06\x03U\x04\x0b\x0c\x04DCSE1\x180\x16\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x0c\x0fhttp2.nikhil.me1\'0%\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\t\x01\x16\x18phd1401101002@iiti.ac.in0\x82\x01"0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x01\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x0f\x000\x82\x01\n\x02\x82\x01\x01\x00\xe1\xc3\x9cN\xc7gDz\xces\xca\'F&\x17\xcb\xe8e\xea\xdd_\x07\x9a\xab\xbf\xc6$\xfe\xf7\x84\x9d\x97|H\xdd3\xfdi\xbf\x17\xfe\x92\xad\x99..q\x97\x00\xcf\xad\xbcd\xe1j\x9e\x9b\xbcq\r\xd2~ \x98\xc8\x8c\x11\xdc\xd3G\x8e\x19b\x98\xde\xff\x13\xae{\xf4\x86\x99\xda\xb3(\\\xad\xd4B\x89\xb1\xdf?\x02\x04P\xe3\xe5\xe4\xa3\x13\xae>\x1e\xff\x18\x12\xd2x\x05\xa8\x88\xffY\xad\xbb\xfc\x95\x06|\xda\x8du&\xe6\'\xdd\xe3bY\xbd\x00\x9c\x14\xb6Kf\xbfu\x96\x87B\x80\x11\xe5d\x90\x0f\x05\x8f,\x95:1\xc1p[\x17\xe7c\x17{+\xc1\x03w\x87\xc1\xc2\x07\x9a<\x96\xa1\x9e\xa2e\xa5Rs\x88x\xd8m\xed\xa4h\xba\x83\xf9m\xd6H\xe0\xf4\x19\x97\xces\xe1\x04\x97\x1ae\xffV\xe6|\xdfV\xd5Q!Z6\xa0\x19C\xe5\xfd\n\xb5P\x9ch\x992\xf8\xce\x85\x15\xb1<\xd2\x95\x06\xa9\x9a\xdf\xa8\xef\x0e2\xa55\xb1Y\x19\x06\xb2y<\xea37e\x02\x03\x01\x00\x01\xa3P0N0\x1d\x06\x03U\x1d\x0e\x04\x16\x04\x149\xfe=n\x15\xa9P\xc5\xd4\x07\x8bF5\xa8\x05N\x0e\xa4\xf6\xa20\x1f\x06\x03U\x1d#\x04\x180\x16\x80\x149\xfe=n\x15\xa9P\xc5\xd4\x07\x8bF5\xa8\x05N\x0e\xa4\xf6\xa20\x0c\x06\x03U\x1d\x13\x04\x050\x03\x01\x01\xff0\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x0b\x05\x00\x03\x82\x01\x01\x00\xbck\x1c\xfb\xc9\xac]\x04\x12b\xc5\xf4!~\xb7\xc6\xa6Q[\x00S\xf2\xb1\xbe\xa1\x8fv\xb0\x90\x1f@Z\x10m<1\xe2\x9c\xf0\x1c\x922|\xde\x02?(#\xee{\xca\xc0\xc1\xe0\x88\xde6\x18,P\xa5\\\xb7\xa8\xa4\x80\xd6w\xc4\x99\xea:\xcf8\xd6\xbd(\xf2\xd7\x85j\x9f\xf7\x7f8\xd8\xcb\xf5?aIM\x97\x988\xe3\xe8t\xf4\x14\x95\xdeI\xc4\xce0\x9c\xbe\xdc7\x1d\xd6<OT\x811\xc2\x9f\xee\x7f{\xd5hJ\x0f\xa6\x8f\xe6\x7f\x18\xcd\x1f\\/\xa2&\xff\x83ee-\x83\x81\xb6\xbe\x05\xd23\xee\xf6\xae\x8e\x8fr\x80\xa0wai\x14Q\xa9\x85\x9e33@\xa6\x11(\x12(\xf9t\xdc& v\x7fw\xab\xc7\xda\xcfOU\x08\xa8\xcf^\xc0z\xfao=I"\x9e<*[\r\t\xc5}\xe3\t\x07\xf07\xd7\xc3\xf7\x1d\xa55\x00w\xdc=\xf0\xae\xec|\xc1\x97\x00\xa4\x9a\xf5e\x05\x92D\x1bl\xa7\xda\xf5\x80*\x96\xfe"J\x9c:\xdb(u\xaf5\x0b\x1cq'
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= handshake
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x14d
   |###[ TLS Handshake ]###
   |     type      = server_key_exchange
   |     length    = 0x149
   |###[ TLS Server Key Exchange ]###
   |###[ TLS EC Diffie-Hellman Server Params ]###
   |           curve_type= named_curve
   |           curve_name= secp256r1
   |           p_length  = 0x41
   |           p         = '\x04\xa8\x11\x0e\x90\x03\xf2\xc3~{=\x8dN\xd4\x1a6bZc0\xac\x02\xc8+\xe09\xaf\x83CO\xa4Z\x99\xc2h\x84\xc0\xb0\xd95Ogp\x949\xcb\xfc/E\tF\x99\xa5\x11\xd8\xb0+\xfd\xa4\xfb\x0c\x01h\xcb1'
   |           hash_type = sha1
   |           sig_type  = rsa
   |           sig_length= 0x100
   |           sig       = "C}\x0f\x02\xf0\xd2\xf1\x91\x01\xae`Gy\\\xf4'\xba\\\x1f\xd8\xbc\xd0\xca\x9e\xff\x9d\xb4\x83t\xdai/IP\xc7\xa0\x9b'\xcc{\xec[\xc7W\x1d\xb0\xd9\x11\xbb\xb8R\xad\xf0\xf6\xcaA{t\x18o/\x8e\xf6\x86\xba2C\xfe`j\xc9=\xd0w\xfbx\xaa\xa6S\x9b\xf8\x80\xf0\x16\xf8\xc1E\xbf\xba\xe1j\xbd\x03u_x}\xae\x86\x7f,U\xf9\xf0\\f\xef\xa5\xa7\xa3\xca`6\x93kH\xfe\xedy\xfc\xb2\xd7\xec\\\x9eg\xc8Ae\x125\xb4\xb1\xa0)\xbd\xc5\xb6@\xee\xcc;3rk\xdey\x81%\x014GH\x9fU\xa1&\x14\x9d\x81<Zu\x95\x14I\xbaEY\xac(\x08nea)\x12\x0fo\xc4\xde\xc2D\x16XA\xcb\x08\x8b\xe0\xebe\x0b\xbb\xfe\xe8\xd7j\xecT\x8a\xbe\xd7V\x8by\x01\xd9\xce\x11\x02\xd1\xa3\xf3\x14\x9a=\xe0\xbf\xe3\xc8=\x0f\xce\x9a\xc2\xb2\x85\x1a\x16y#[+y\xefq\xb3?\x8f=}\x91\xc9\x06\xe0[\xce;\x92n_\x91\xb9m^"
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= handshake
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x4
   |###[ TLS Handshake ]###
   |     type      = server_hello_done
   |     length    = 0x0
###[ SSL/TLS ]###
  \records   \
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= change_cipher_spec
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x1
   |###[ TLS ChangeCipherSpec ]###
   |     message   = '\x01'
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= handshake
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x50
   |###[ TLS Handshake ]###
   |     type      = finished
   |     length    = 0xc
   |     explicit_iv= 'g\xb2N\xb3y,\xa9\n\xc6\x9d\xc7m\xc9\xe5\x11['
   |     mac       = '\xdaw0\x9fF\xd3\xa7?P\xf26\xa5\xb8`A\x90p\x07G\xfa\x92\xe2\x86\x98\x02\x94G\xc0\x90\xe2\xc2\xd2'
   |     padding   = '\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f\x0f'
   |     padding_len= 0xf
   |###[ TLS Handshake Finished ]###
   |        data      = '\x87\x1f!\xc7\x177&\xd7\xcb\x1b$\x00'
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= application_data
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x60
   |###[ TLS Plaintext ]###
   |     data      = '\x00\x00\x1a\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0cUnknown error code'
   |     explicit_iv= '\xac3`\x01\xcdF3\x1b\x98H\xcc\xe2\xb6\x97\xa1\xca'
   |     mac       = '\xf8l5\xab\x044>\xd4\x17F\xba\xe0\xff:\xbf\xed\xcbf \xcf\x1f\xd0\xb8\xc2\xd5\xec\x05\xc2e\x01\xcd_'
   |     padding   = '\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c\x0c'
   |     padding_len= 0xc
   |###[ TLS Record ]###
   |  content_type= alert
   |  version   = TLS_1_2
   |  length    = 0x40
   |###[ TLS Alert ]###
   |     level     = warning
   |     description= close_notify
   |     explicit_iv= '\x89\r\xf5\xbe,R\x0e8\xad5c\x05\x99\xea\xeb\x80'
   |     mac       = 'c\xef\x08\xbfI\xf5\x85E\xd9\xb8\xa5C\n@\xdc\xf6\x96\x03\xdb\xb4\x0b\xb7\x04\x84?\x80R\xa8\xfd\xaa\x16\x99'
   |     padding   = '\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r\r'
   |     padding_len= 0xd
Finished handshake. Sending application data (GET request)
+++++++++++++++++
+++++++++++++++++
Got response from server
###[ SSL/TLS ]###
  \records   \
<TLSSessionCtx: id=140259983147536
     params.handshake.client=<TLSClientHello  version=TLS_1_2 cipher_suites=['ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256'] compression_methods=['NULL'] extensions=[<TLSExtension  type=application_layer_protocol_negotiation |<TLSExtALPN  protocol_name_list=[<TLSALPNProtocol  data='h2' |>, <TLSALPNProtocol  data='h2-16' |>, <TLSALPNProtocol  data='h2-14' |>, <TLSALPNProtocol  data='http/1.1' |>] |>>] |>
     params.handshake.server=<TLSServerHello  version=TLS_1_2 gmt_unix_time=1964528416 random_bytes='\xa5\x11\x11\x81\xc3V\x03Q\xdb>\x8b\x1d\x9e\x13\xa7\xfelT\x80\x97\xf5\x06.4\x18\xc8\x85X' session_id_length=0x20 session_id='\x93\xfd\x95\xbc\x1d68w\x19{8\x83dz\xb4\\r\x81\xb7&\xb5\x14\x1d\xfc<fR\x00\xe7\xd3{\x90' cipher_suite=ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 compression_method=NULL extensions_length=0x9 extensions=[<TLSExtension  type=application_layer_protocol_negotiation length=0x5 |<TLSExtALPN  length=0x3 protocol_name_list=[<TLSALPNProtocol  length=0x2 data='h2' |>] |>>] |>
     params.negotiated.version=TLS_1_2
     params.negotiated.ciphersuite=ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     params.negotiated.key_exchange=ECDHE
     params.negotiated.encryption=('AES', 16, 'CBC')
     params.negotiated.mac=SHA256
     params.negotiated.compression=NULL
     crypto.client.enc=<Crypto.Cipher.AES.AESCipher instance at 0x7f90d13062d8>
     crypto.client.dec=<Crypto.Cipher.AES.AESCipher instance at 0x7f90d13063b0>
     crypto.server.enc=<Crypto.Cipher.AES.AESCipher instance at 0x7f90d13063f8>
     crypto.server.dec=<Crypto.Cipher.AES.AESCipher instance at 0x7f90d1306440>
     crypto.client.rsa.privkey=None
     crypto.client.rsa.pubkey=None
     crypto.server.rsa.privkey=None
     crypto.server.rsa.pubkey=<_RSAobj @0x7f90d13464d0 n(2048),e>
     crypto.client.dsa.privkey=None
     crypto.client.dsa.pubkey=None
     crypto.server.dsa.privkey=None
     crypto.server.dsa.pubkey=None
     crypto.client.dh.x=None
     crypto.client.dh.y_c=None
     crypto.server.dh.p=None
     crypto.server.dh.g=None
     crypto.server.dh.x=None
     crypto.server.dh.y_s=None
     crypto.client.ecdh.curve_name=None
     crypto.client.ecdh.priv='\x9d\xa1\xc1)\xc7g\xcf+\xc1U\xffd\x0f\xd13\xf3G0\xb3>\x83\x8b1V\xa19S\xac\xb4\xe8\x18_'
     crypto.client.ecdh.pub=(55660150079706264549060731250077677621567952543805917063205824042726931277737, 96171213429541138775191303156783500559576917020503549099364694827291830154118) on "secp256r1" => y^2 = x^3 + 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853948x + 41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291 (mod 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951)
     crypto.server.ecdh.curve_name='secp256r1'
     crypto.server.ecdh.priv=None
     crypto.server.ecdh.pub=(76018695469186964965485429908810690080098805676135269709416857701937687321241, 87933360945342485384088790667444373602059838780977372442846636781953482279729) on "secp256r1" => y^2 = x^3 + 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853948x + 41058363725152142129326129780047268409114441015993725554835256314039467401291 (mod 115792089210356248762697446949407573530086143415290314195533631308867097853951)
     crypto.session.encrypted_premaster_secret=None
     crypto.session.premaster_secret='\x8e\xd6\xf6\xe0)\x03\x07pd\x15OvRT\xa7\x1f\x1d\xe0|k\x13\xaa\xc3\xf7_>\xa9X\x08\xe3\xaa\x98'
     crypto.session.master_secret='\x02\x91N\x90\xcc\xe7\xda\\\xf7!\x82\x9e\xf374@p\x07\xdfJM\x98\xcen_78\x1e\xf8\xdfo`\xc4\xde\x82\x9dw\x1c\xcb\xcf\xa8>\xe0\xe2\xc7\xbc\x84F'
     crypto.session.randombytes.client='X\xea!\xf6\xe7S\xd8\xa6\xb9\x97\xd1nt\x96\x0e|W\xe9\xe2\xf4\xb95/F=D5\xcbu\x02r\x00'
     crypto.session.randombytes.server='u\x18S \xa5\x11\x11\x81\xc3V\x03Q\xdb>\x8b\x1d\x9e\x13\xa7\xfelT\x80\x97\xf5\x06.4\x18\xc8\x85X'
     crypto.session.key.client.mac='\x9d\xd7~\x9e\xd8\x89\x9b\x19\x0fN\xcb\xf3\xe3H\x08\xdfj\xe3h\xdaZ,\x1d\x08\xf8\xa3<\xe0!\xeb=\x85'
     crypto.session.key.client.encryption='\xe2Z\xdf\\/\x18~\xd2\xc2G\xe6\xc9\x916.}'
     crypto.session.key.cllient.iv='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
     crypto.session.key.server.mac='\x90\x83^ ]\x8d\xef\x06\xae\xed\x1an\xe2\x15\x9c4\xb8\x8d\xc4>g\xc4\xcdXU\xe7\xc3\xa9yvQ\x87'
     crypto.session.key.server.encryption='\xaf\xb76E\xbe@\x1cj\xbc\xbas\xb8+\xa9\xaf\x0e'
     crypto.session.key.server.iv='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
     crypto.session.key.length.mac=32
     crypto.session.key.length.encryption=16
     crypto.session.key.length.iv=16
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not sending any HTTP/2 request to the server, so you can't expect a response.

`sock.sendall(to_raw(TLSPlaintext(data="PRI * HTTP/2.0\r\n\r\nSM\r\n\r\n"), sock.tls_ctx))`

will only send the HTTP/2 client preface to the server, which is the first part from client side for starting up a HTTP/2 **connection**. According to the specification you also have to send HTTP/2 settings frame (in binary form) after that. After this you may send a HTTP/2 request, which consists of a HPACK encoded HEADERS frame and potentially following DATA frames. The server should then respond with associated HEADERS and DATA frames as response. Before this you will also receive the servers SETTINGS frame, and potentially a SETTINGS acknowledge for your own SETTINGS.